# Although my code is returning String the function still expects to return string

Tags: java

// Even after returning the success message i am still getting String return expected... 
// Any help will be appreciated

```
public String addStudent(Student student) throws Exception 
{
    try
    {
        Validator validate = new Validator();
        validate.validate(student);
        if((student.getMark1()<50 && student.getMark2()<50 && student.getMark3()<50) && student.getResult()=='P')
            throw new Exception("Service.INVALID_RESULT_PASS");
        if((student.getMark1()>=50 || student.getMark2()>=50 || student.getMark3()>=50) && student.getResult()=='F')
            throw new Exception("Service.INVALID_RESULT_FAIL");
        return "Success";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the entirety of `try` and `catch`, only keep the inner part of `try` in the method.

Comment: what if it catches an exception ?

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 but i must handle the exception in this function only...

Comment: then why do you have a `throws Exception` declared? And what do you return if an exception is encountered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that your IDE is saying that it still wants a return, its because the code is not guarrenteed to return something. It doesn't return something if an exception is thrown, so try returning something at the end of the code, like:

```
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

(I haven't typed all the code, but you get the point)

Comment: Thanks @peter but it will address a null pointer exception if null is returned and if an exception is thrown my program will handle it due to try catch block and if not i'm expected to return "Success" message...

Comment: @Anand then just `return "Success";` intstead of `return "";`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't telling Java what to return if an `Exception` is caught. You will need to add a return statement to your `catch` block or outside the `try/catch` block.

That being said, you are throwing a new `Exception` from within your `try/catch` block, which is odd.

If you want to throw those Exceptions yourself, then the `try/catch` is not needed here.